# Coffeescript tree extends class not working

Tags: javascript, tree, coffeescript, extends

I need to create a tree that, for example CALCULATE 2 numbers. I do in coffee script, who connvert javascript due to extend class.

```js
class Expression
 @Evaluate = -> 0
    
class Const extends Expression
 constructor: (value)->
  
class BinaryOperation extends Expression
 constructor: (L, R)->
  
class Add extends BinaryOperation
 @Evaluate = -> L.Evaluate() + R.Evaluate();

expr = new Add(new Const(10), new Const(10));
alert(expr.Evaluate())
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/f3ry/D9kBP/24/
Thanks.

Comment: None of your subclasses actually do anything. And you're trying to write a parser in coffeescript because.....?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is a combination of syntax errors and a misunderstanding of how subclassing works. This should get you there:

```
class Expression
    Evaluate: () -> 0

class Const extends Expression
    constructor: (@value) ->
    Evaluate: () -> @value

class BinaryOperation extends Expression
    constructor: (@L, @R)->

class Add extends BinaryOperation
    Evaluate: -> @L.Evaluate() + @R.Evaluate();

expr = new Add(new Const(10), new Const(10));
alert(expr.Evaluate())
```

Adding the `@` to the constructor parameter sets it as a property of the newly created object. Overriding the `Evaluate` method allows the operations to be performed. [Link to example](http://coffeescript.org/#try:class%20Expression%0A%20%20%20%20Evaluate%3A%20()%20-%3E%200%0A%0Aclass%20Const%20extends%20Expression%0A%20%20%20%20constructor%3A%20(%40value)%20-%3E%0A%20%20%20%20Evaluate%3A%20()%20-%3E%20%40value%0A%0Aclass%20BinaryOperation%20extends%20Expression%0A%20%20%20%20constructor%3A%20(%40L%2C%20%40R)-%3E%0A%0Aclass%20Add%20extends%20BinaryOperation%0A%20%20%20%20Evaluate%3A%20-%3E%20%40L.Evaluate()%20%2B%20%40R.Evaluate()%3B%0A%0Aexpr%20%3D%20new%20Add(new%20Const(10)%2C%20new%20Const(10))%3B%0Aalert(expr.Evaluate())).

Answer (score 0):

I create syntax tree with abstract classes. In python working very good:

```
class Expression:
    def Evaluate(self):
        return 0;

class Const(Expression):
    def __init__(self, nValue):
        self.Value = nValue;

    def Evaluate(self):
        return self.Value;

class BinaryOperation(Expression):
    def __init__(self, nL, nR):
        self.L = nL;
        self.R = nR;

class Add(BinaryOperation):

    def Evaluate(self):
        return self.L.Evaluate() + self.R.Evaluate();
```